# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier - can not find it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I go to `#retern_car` I have:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

All the rest `cars_galery`, `log_in` and `load_home` show no error.

I have only one page using load to load different content so only my body changing the footer and the head stay. I load my content to `body_page` div:

```
$('document').ready(function(){

//console.log(cars);
if(localStorage.cars==null){
    saveToLocalStoregeCars();
}
//var int=self.setInterval(function(){imeg_change()},2000);


var index=0;
var selected_vehicle;
var car_to_retern;
var rental_car_number;

//console.log('test');
var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();

$('#year').html(' '+currentYear);   

$('#cars_galery').click(function(){
    $("#body_page").load("car_galery.html");
});
$('#retern_car').click(function(){
    $("#body_page").load("Retern_car.html");
});
$('#log_in').click(function(){
    $("#body_page").load("new_user.html");
});
$('#load_home').click(function(){
    $("#body_page").load("home.html");
});



$(document).on('click','.product',function(){

    $("#body_page").load("map-for-parts.html");


     selected_vehicle=$(this).parent().attr('id');
     console.log('selected_vehicle= '+selected_vehicle);
     localStorage.selected_vehicle=selected_vehicle;


     localStorage.carImeg=$("#"+selected_vehicle +" img").attr('src');

     console.log(' localStorage.carImeg =  '+localStorage.carImeg);

     localStorage.carNumber=$("#"+selected_vehicle +" .car_number").text();
      console.log(' localStorage.carNumber =  '+ localStorage.carNumber);


        });
      });



    function load_new_user_form(){

    $("#body_page").load("new_user.html");

     }


   ////////////////////////
   // Local Storege

   function saveToLocalStoregeCars(){
localStorage.cars=JSON.stringify(cars); 
   }

   function getFromLocalStoregeCars(){
if (localStorage.cars)
    cars=JSON.parse(localStorage.cars); 
   }

  function saveToLocalStoregeCarsOnRent(){
localStorage.cars_on_rent=JSON.stringify(cars_on_rent); 
   }

    function getFromLocalStoregeCarsOnRent(){
if (localStorage.cars_on_rent)
    cars_on_rent=JSON.parse(localStorage.cars_on_rent); 
      }

       // Local Storege
       //////////////////////// 
       var imeg=1;
       function imeg_change(){

       $('.content').css({"background-image":"url(imeg/car"+imeg+".jpg)"});
       imeg++;
       if (imeg==5){ imeg=1;}
       console.log('imeg_change');
      }
```

Comment: Is the `#retern_car` element present on the page on page load or is it being added dynamically later on?

Comment: You mean when you click on `#retern_car`? Then the `retern_car.html` is loaded, so that will contain an error.

Comment: Just a small remark: your javascript is horribly formatted. Please fix formatting, with consequent indenting. Man, even if a look away for a second I have to start from the top again to comprehend it.

Comment: No, my question was about the `#retern_car` element (`div`, `button`, `a`, or whatever it is).  When do you add that element to the page? Is it part of the original HTML? Or do you add it to the page via some JS?

Comment: Does `Retern_car.html` contain Javascript? The error is almost certainly in that file.

Comment: #retern_car it is not a part of the page i add it later